# Compute $\frac{1}{2\pi}\int_0^{2\pi}f(t)g(t)dt$ where $g(t)= \sum\limits_{n=1}^\infty \frac{(-1)^n}{n}\sin(nt)$

Tags: real-analysis, integration, fourier-analysis

> Fourier analysis, compute integral $\dfrac{1}{2\pi}\int_0^{2\pi}f(t)g(t)dt$ where $g(t)= \sum_{n=1}^\infty \dfrac{(-1)^n}{n}\sin(nt)$ and $f(t)=\cos(t)+7\sin(2t)$.

I'm having slight problems solving this integral, can we use alternating series test to say that the sum converges in some way? It feels like the sum might converge to $0$ and that we in that case will get an integal that is just $0$, but that feels counterintuitive so I'm unsure. Is there some theorem that might help that I'm missing?

Comment: What is $f(t)$? And can't you use the closed form of $g(t)$?

Comment: Thanks! forgot to add $f(t)$ have now added it.

Comment: I don't know if you are supposed to recognize this, but I think $g(t)$ is the same as $-t/2$ (which makes this just an integration by parts problem).

Comment: Remember that for $|x|<\pi$, $$x^2=\frac{\pi^2}3+4\sum_{n\geq1}\frac{(-1)^n}{n^2}\cos nx$$ So then you take $d/dx$ on both sides to get $$-2x=4\sum_{n\geq1}\frac{(-1)^n}{n}\sin nx$$ so we have that $$g(x)=-\frac{x}2$$

Comment: @Rellek here $g(t)=-t/2$ when $t\in[-\pi,\pi]$, but he is integrating in $[0,2\pi]$, in this set $$g(t)=\begin{cases}-t/2,&t\in[0,\pi)\\\pi-t/2,&t\in(\pi,2\pi]\\0,&t=\pi\end{cases}$$

Comment: Please use `\frac` in titles, not `\dfrac`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The sum for $g$ converges in $L^2$ because $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{n^2} < \infty$ and because $\{ s_n(x)=\frac{\sin(nt)}{\sqrt{\pi}} \}_{n=1}^{\infty}$ is an orthonormal subset of $L^2[0,2\pi]$. That is,
$$
      g_N(t) = \sum_{n=1}^{N}\frac{(-1)^n}{n}\sin(nt)
$$
converges in $L^2$ to some $g\in L^2$. Because of this,
$$
    \int_{0}^{2\pi}g(t)f(t)dt=\lim_{N}\int_{0}^{2\pi}g_N(t)f(t)dt \\
    = \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{(-1)^n}{n}\int_{0}^{2\pi}\sin(nt)f(t)dt \\
    = \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{(-1)^n}{n}\int_{0}^{2\pi}\sin(nt)(\cos(t)+7\sin(2t))dt.
$$

The functions $\{ 1,\cos(t),\sin(t),\cos(2t),\sin(2t),\cdots \}$ are mutually orthogonal. So the above reduces to

$$
     \frac{7}{2}\int_0^{2\pi}\sin^2(2t)dt=\frac{7\pi}{2}.
$$
Therefore,
$$
     \frac{1}{2\pi}\int_{0}^{2\pi}f(t)g(t)dt = \frac{7}{4}.
$$

Comment: it is not enough clear that, because $g_n$ converges in $L^2$, we can exchange sum and integral. I will say that we can do this because $f\in L^2$ also and the inner product in  $L^2(\Bbb R)$ is bounded and hence continuous, so $$\lim_{n\to\infty}(g_n|f)=(g| f)$$